# Embed Javascript in php file, syntax

Tags: javascript, php

Using ajax I post data to php file where I have loop with code below.

Part of my code where I can't properly format onclick event:

```
$result .= '<a href="#" onclick="$("#element").dialog("open");" ></a>';
```

I tried to escape double quotes with backslash, but no luck. Using backslashes, in console I see:  Somehow from nowhere "=" appears, also all backslashes are printed. Code doesn't work.

Could someone help to figure out where I made a mistake in syntax? Thank you.

Comment: Edited, to better explain why I didn't find answer in other posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your string there are double quotes, followed by content wrapped again in double quotes. The second quotes should be single quotes, but that would terminate the string. So you will have to escape them.

The desired html code should look like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="$('#element').dialog('open');"></a>
```

to achieve this, you will have to change your PHP code to the e.g. the following:

```
$result .= '<a href="#" onclick="$(\'#element\').dialog(\'open\');"></a>';
```

Answer (score 1):

When parsing the HTML, the browser will read the `onclick="$("#element"` part, and infer that attribute `onclick` equals `"$("`, because it thought it found the closing double quotes. So, you'll need to escape the double quote character after the `$(`. Since you're using `$result .= 'some_string'` (I want to empasize on the single quote being used here), you are [unable to escape](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3446286/1807809) the double quote character within the single quoted string. Thus, you'll need something like this: 

`$result .= '<a href="#" onclick="$(\'#element\').dialog(\'open\');" ></a>';`

Now, php will translate `\'` to just `'` while rendering, so the final output of the string will be

`<a href="#" onclick="$('#element').dialog('open');" ></a>`

I hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

Double quotes should be escaped

```
$result .= '<a href="#" onclick="$(\"#element\").dialog(\"open\");" ></a>';
```

Another way is

```
$result .= `<a href="#" onclick="$('#element').dialog('open');" ></a>`;
```

Comment: Shouldn't `dialog("open")` be escaped then too?

Comment: Plus, I think those backticks in your second code won't work.

Comment: Previously I tried to escape double quotes, but no luch. Also this time in console I see: <a href="#" onclick="$(\" #element\").dialog(\"open\");"="">
Somehow from nowhere I see "=", from where it comes? Also code doesn't work.

Comment: It worked after I changed double quotes to single... <a href="#" onclick="$(\'#element\').dialog(\'open\');" ></a>

Comment: Of course it needs to be escaped otherwise the PHP string will be terminated as it starts with a singe quote.

Comment: Backtick in PHP is to execute a shell command not to define a string literal